# Unbind right click if click once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to unbind right click  if it is clicked once it after unbinding left click should work the code i used for clicking is

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
        document.oncontextmenu =function(){return false;};


        $(document).mousedown(function(e){

            //alert(e.button);
            if( e.button == 0){
                 alert('right click');
             }
             if( e.button == 2){
                 alert('Left click');

             }

        });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using your original unedited code] you could move the `flag` checks inside the right click `if`:

```
    flag=0;
    $(document).mousedown(function(e){
      if( e.button == 0){
        if(flag==0){
           alert('right click');
           flag=1;
        }
      }
      if( e.button == 2){
        alert('Left click');
      }
    });
```

This will give you a

- single right mousedown
- no limit on left mousedown

---

Bit confusing from your wording, but looks like you actually want

- no left mousedown until right mousedown
- one right mousedown then disables right mousedown and enables left mousedown/click

You could do this with similar code

```
    flag=0;
    $(document).mousedown(function(e){
      if (flag==0) {
        if( e.button == 0){
           alert('right click');
           flag=1;
        }
      }
      else {
        if( e.button == 2){
          alert('Left click');
        }
      }
    });
```

---

Having said that, `mousedown` is *not* the same as a click.

A click is both mousedown *and* mouseup within a short time.  If you're used to clicking (down+up) then something happening when you only mousedown will be confusing and could be annoying.

So, using Kriggs suggestion, you could use `.one` on mousedown, but you'd need to rebind if it wasn't right-mouse, so use `.on` and `.off` then bind click after:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function() {
    if (e.button==0) {
       $(document).off("mousedown")
       $(document).click(function() {
           alert("left click");
       });
    }
});
```

This gives you:

- no left click until right mousedown
- one right mousedown then no more mousedown
- left click after right mousedown

Answer (score 0):

Use `.one`, along with `mousedown`, append the `onclick` inside the function of the `.one`.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: if i used  `.one´, along with 'mousedown'. will my left click work ?